# Custom WP form which changes user role on submit

Tags: php, wordpress, roles

Basically I have a page which displays to a user only when they're logged in, it has a custom contact form on it. When the form is submitted, their user role should automatically change to  "Author".

I literally have no idea where to start with this, if anyone has any ideas or can help me out a little that would be amazing because I'm really struggling with this.

**EDIT**

This is what I currently have, all it does at the minute is send emails.

```
<?php
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']));
    $email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
    $subject = trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject']));
    $message = trim(stripslashes($_POST['message']));

    $email_from = $email;
    $email_to = 'email@email.com';

    $body = '<html><head></head><body>' .
            '<b>Name:</b> ' . $name . '<br><br>' .
            '<b>Email:</b> ' . $email . '<br><br>' .
            '<b>Nature of Enquiry:</b> ' . $subject . '<br><br>' .
            '<b>Message:</b> ' . nl2br($message) .
            '</body></html>';

    $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($email_from) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($email_from) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    if( isset($_POST['checkbox']) ) {
      mail($email_to, $subject, $body, $headers);
      // Change user role to "author
      echo '<p>You are now an author.</p>';
    } else {
      echo '<p>It appears you are a spambot, if this is a mistake please try again and check the "I am not a spambot" checkbox.</p>';
    }
  }
?>

<form method="post" action="#">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" required>

  <label for="email">Email Address</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" required>

  <label for="subject">Nature of Enquiry</label>
  <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" value="<?php echo $subject; ?>" required>

  <label for="checkbox">I am not a spambot</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox">

  <label for="message">Message</label>
  <textarea id="message" name="message" required><?php echo $message; ?></textarea>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Start building the form and its submit actions. Do you already have it? During the form successful process, fire the role change.

Comment: @brasofilo Yeah it's the role change part that I'm not sure how to achieve.

Comment: Well, post your actual code and some attempt you're making. Questions without that are normally close voted, see [ask] and http://sscce.org

Comment: @brasofilo Updated it with my current code.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a matter of using the [class `WP_User` and its `set_role` method](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User#set_role.28.24role.29).

```
$user_id = 2;
$role_name = 'author';
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );
$user->set_role( $role_name );
```